# Is mysql-proxy ready for production use?

Tags: mysql, proxy

I've been doing a bit of research, and I would *love* to use mysql-proxy in production, because

1. It supports sockets
2. It supports read-write splitting

My other option is to use HAProxy and change all the configuration files to use TCP/IP rather than sockets.

I see that mysql-proxy is STILL in alpha, however there seems to be lots of development on it and it has been around for quite a while.

Can anyone recommend mysql-proxy in production in a high volume environment? Or should I just give up on this idea?

Answer (score 2):

At present, MySQL Proxy is nothing more that just good IP redirection.

[@DTest in the DBA StackExchange](https://dba.stackexchange.com/users/180/dtest) has addressed MySQL Proxy only twice

- `Dec 17, 2012` : [MySql proxy to replication configuration](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/30622/877)
- `Apr 19, 2012` : [What's the latest on MySQL Proxy?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/16760/877)

Everything that can be customized about MySQL Proxy is only proof-of-concept at the moment. IMHO, the major challenge is the fact that such customization is implemented in the [**LUA language**](http://www.lua.org/). The greatest customization most are looking for is the read/write splitting among designated IP Addresses.

If anyone has successfully implemented Read/Write Splitting using MySQL Proxy, I am sure it is being kept as a well-guarded secret by some SuperSmart LUA Programmer/Business Person waiting to sell their consulting services to the highest bidder.

Comment: hmmm im unsure because some docs say

Comment: I know this question is old but just wanted to point out that mysql-proxy IS NOT written in lua, lua is just used for the user scripts, the application itself is in C.

Comment: @Schmurfy I was only referring to the holy grail of MySQL Proxy everyone is looking for : The read-write split. I'll update the language of my answer to reflect that. Thank you.